# Ionic 4: Change the language of app back and forth with a button

Tags: angular, ionic4, ngx-translate

I need to create a button that will change the language of my Ionic/Angular app.  I currently have two buttons, one that translates the app to english, and a second that translates the app to french.  I would like it to look as if there is only one button that can translate back and forth between french and english but I do not know how to do it.

here is what I have so far:

```
html:
<ion-button color="primary" slot="end" (click)="useLanguage('en')">{{ 'EN-BTN' | 
translate }}</ion-button>

<ion-button color="primary" slot="end" (click)="useLanguage('fr')">{{ 'FR-BTN' | 
translate }}</ion-button>


ts:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-language-btn',
  templateUrl: './language-btn.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./language-btn.component.scss'],
})
export class LanguageBtnComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.setDefaultLang('en'); }

    useLanguage(language: string) {
      this.translate.use(language);
    }
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution is to just toggle a boolean when button is clicked, if you want english to be the default we can use for example `isEn = true` initially...

```
isEn = true;

useLanguage() {
  this.isEn = !this.isEn;
  isEn ? this.translate.use('en') : this.translate.use('fr');
}
```

As for the button, you could use:

```
<ion-button color="primary" slot="end" (click)="useLanguage()">
  <span *ngIf="isEn">{{ 'EN-BTN' | translate }}</span>
  <span *ngIf="!isEn">{{ 'FR-BTN' | translate }}</span>
</ion-button>
```